# Starting server in screen with ssh does not create screen session

Tags: command-line, server, ssh

I'm trying to compose a single command that will start server in screen on remote machine. `ssh user@host "cd workingdirectory/ ; screen -dmS server ./start.sh"` also tried with `-t` and `-f` flags for ssh command. When I execute `cd workingdirectory/ ; screen -dmS server ./start.sh` while connected via ssh it works correctly, but when I run it with ssh part the screen does not launch. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you running the ssh command from a terminal, or from some environment with no terminal (for example from a webserver script)? From what I remember, `screen` needs a terminal to start.

Comment: I tried both from linux terminal and python paramiko with similar results. If it would be the case, do you know any workaround?

Comment: I would try to write an `expect` script that logs in to server via ssh, starts `screen` and logs out. `expect` explicitly simulates a terminal. If you are able to start `screen` in a ssh session, this solution should work.

Comment: I have found paramiko-expect python library and it started the server successfully, you were right, thanks!